# Was this scene an homage to Hellboy?

Tags: reference, pacific-rim, hellboy, guillermo-del-toro

In one scene, Ron Perlman's character is eaten by a giant monster.  This isn't the first time this has happened to him in a del Toro movie, it also somewhat happened in Hellboy.  Was this scene supposed to be an homage to Hellboy, or am I reading too much into it?

Comment: Beat me to this question!

Comment: To me its look like Homage to Japanese Monster films.

Answer (score 11):

During the scene after the end credits, we see Perlman cut his way out of the Kaiju and then exclaim "Where's my Damn Shoe!?"

That whole bit where he gets swallowed (by a premature Birthed Kaiju with no teeth) was simple comedy relief scene to show that the character portrayed didn't know everything, but maintains posturing as though he does.

I doubt this was a nod or anything like that to Hellboy.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Rim_%28film%29#Design) page of the movie:

> Del Toro wanted to "honor" the kaiju and mecha genres while creating an original stand-alone film, something "conscious of the heritage, but not a pastiche or an homage or a greatest hits of everything". The director made a point of starting from scratch, without emulating or referencing any previous examples of those genres.

It doesn't refer Hellboy but it explicitly says that Del Toro doesn't want to pay homage to any film. Rather than popular culture, he drew inspiration from works of art such as  Francisco Goya's The Colossus and George Bellows's boxing paintings.

Comment: @Mistu4u its Francisco Goya's The Colossus.

Comment: Aha! Ok, I misinterpreted!

Comment: That said, the original question isn't asking for the inspiration for the film - rather, Dforck is considering the fact that Ron Pearlman's character was swallowed by a large, tenticled beastie in both PacRim and the first Hellboy movie.

Comment: @Nobby The answer is not directly answering Hellboy homage but it refers to overall homage reply of Del toro

Comment: Right - which in my opinion does not make this a valid answer.

Comment: that's funny. I allways thought the "Gipsy Danger" design was an homage to "Gigantor"